# jQuery image resizing according to resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery snipper but it seems not to be working. The script is supposed to resize (with an animation) all the images with the 'img' id as soon as the window's width is lower than 960px. Here's the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 960)
    {               
        $('.img').animate({ width: '100px' });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.img').animate({ width: '200px' });
    }
     });
});
</script>
```

The HTML code for the images:

```
<figure><a href="/index.php?ll={LANG}&pag=test"><img src="img/test/1.jpg" class="img"><figcaption>{IMG1_FOOTER}</figcaption></a></figure>
```

Any idea why this isn't working as expected?

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have multiple images on the same page? If so you should use `class="img"`, you should not have multiple elements with same id on the page.

Comment: @Dan True thing. I already replaced ids for classes, although it doesn't work.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/6p8oq74L/1/

Comment: Well, it appears to be bugged for me (I'm using Chrome). When I load the page, the images are big. Then I resize the window to less than 960 and they get smaller, but it isn't getting the old size back when I make the window bigger.